# When using google wallet payments api can a user pre-authorise future transactions?

Tags: in-app-purchase, android-pay

I am building a webapp which requires users to regularly top up their account. To allow for this I am exploring the google wallet inapp payments api and have got this working fine. However, I would like users to be given the option to auto-top up when their account balance becomes low. I have looked at the [subscription documentation](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/subscriptions?hl=en) but cannot see whether this is possible or not - it seems you can only have a subscription which draws money at regular intervals. 
Is there a way to have a user pre-authorise this kind of transaction, and if so could you please point me to any documentation that would allow for this?

Comment: For anyone reading this Stripe has this feature (Just released in the UK). They store a users card for future use and enable you to make future charges. Pretty cool - and the deal breaker between me and google-wallet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. The subscription feature is probably your best bet and should (unless I'm missing something) get you to the "same place".

A "pre-authorization" somewhat says, you'll come back at some later time to *charge* (aka "capture") the pre-auth. There is no API command that does that (capture/charge) in Wallet for Digital Goods. The process is immediate...

There (is) used to be one in the Google Checkout API where you are given 7 calendar days to *charge* a pre-auth. However, this product will be [retired in November](https://support.google.com/checkout/sell/answer/3080449).

Comment: Hi EdSF. I don't think the subscription feature could get me to the same place. I'm after something like the auto-recharge that Skype has implemented using paypal (https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1042/what-is-auto-recharge-and-how-does-it-work). I can't seen how I could achieve the same thing using GW.

Comment: @user714852 Am confused, that **is** "subscription", the charge occurs on specified future dates / intervals....

Comment: Hi EdSF. Apologies - I'm not being clear. The key bit I'm getting at is "Auto-recharge automatically tops up your Skype Credit when your balance falls below a certain figure (typically $2 / €2 / £2)". To me this means (and from experience) I can have multiple payments to Skype in a day if I make a lot of calls. This is different to a 'subscription' which would only charge me on specified future dates / intervals. Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: @user714852 Got it, "metering" - quite interesting! Anyway, unless you do this on your own (programmatically do the topping off using your own params, within your app), there isn't anything out of the box...